# JavaScript: How to convert julian date to gregorian?

Tags: javascript, date

I have the date: 1830-02-24 
It is old format (julian)

How to convert this to new style (gregorian) on javascript?

UPD: Not Gregorian to Julian, just **Julian to Gregorian**

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370688/convert-a-julian-date-to-regular-date-in-javascript

Comment: This is converting from gregorian to julian. I need opposite

Comment: Take a look at http://forums.ultraedit.com/julian-date-to-gregorian-date-conversion-script-t6948.html

Comment: A Julian date is a continuous count of days since -4712-01-01T12:00:00 (i.e. the start of 4713 BC), e.g. 2018-03-18T06:39:30.0 is 2458195.777431. What does the string "1830-02-24" represent? It doesn't appear to be a Julian date. See [*USNO Julian date converter*](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php#juld).