# How to do cells.setNumberFormat("d.M.yyyy") in GAS in memory only?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got 5 digit Julian date (I hope it is Julian date, I just got this data and need to work with it) in a Google Sheet (`26933`) that I can convert to human readable form by clicking `Format - Date`. So it becomes `26.09.1973`.

I found that I can do the same using Google Application Script when I use this code `cells.setNumberFormat("d.M.yyyy");`

but it changes the format of the sheet. How can I achieve the same only in memory not changing the sheet at all?

Comment: can you elaborate more on that: `achieve the same only in memory` . You mean you want to use the date in a script (but not change the sheet at all) ?

Comment: yes, exactly. You are right @soMario

Answer (score 2):

if you want to convert a julian date to a regular date using javascript then here is the thread you should be focusing on:

[Convert a Julian Date to regular date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370688/convert-a-julian-date-to-regular-date-in-javascript/36073807)

However, if you are looking for a Google Apps Script trick, then you can change the format, get the date and then change the format back to the original (julian date):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rng = sh.getRange("A1");
  rng.setNumberFormat("d.M.yyyy");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const dt = rng.getDisplayValue();
  rng.setNumberFormat("#")
  
  console.log(dt); // work with dt
}
```